# Can't install wine on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS (broken packages)

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, ubuntu-studio

I've following this "https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu".

I've tried with so much guides with no result and now is a bit different.

Command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

Result:

```
Obj:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Obj:2 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Des:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Obj:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Obj:5 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Des:6 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Obj:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease                
Obj:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Descargados 214 kB en 2s (138 kB/s)
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_CL) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_CL) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
```

Command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Result:

```
Obj:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Des:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                             
Obj:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                 
Obj:4 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                           
Obj:5 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                         
Des:6 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Obj:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu impish InRelease
Obj:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Descargados 214 kB en 2s (108 kB/s)
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Todos los paquetes están actualizados.
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_CL) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_CL) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:60 y /etc/apt/sources.list:62
```

Command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Result:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 winehq-stable : Depende: wine-stable (= 6.0.2~impish-1)
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

In even with the snap store:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.

And when I try other commands for wine like `sudo apt install wine` or `sudo apt install wine32` or `sudo apt install wine64`.

I got this:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 wine64 : Depende: libwine (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) pero no va a instalarse
          Recomienda: wine32 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1)
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

So I have this problem and I need a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this unchecking all the boxes with the word "wine" on /etc/apt/sources.list > Other software